# How to account for revealed cards in a model of a poorly shuffled deck?

Tags: probability

Let's say we shuffle decks of cards together so that we know the exact probabilities of each card ending up in a given position in the resulting deck.

For example, some card c could be as follows:
$$
P(c\ in\ position\ 16)=.5\\
P(c\ in\ position\ 17)=.2\\
P(c\ in\ position\ 18)=.3
$$

## Example case: A three card deck.

We've cards $c_1, c_2, c_3$ that all behave as follows
$$
P(c_n\ in\ position\ n) = 0.6\\
P(c_n\ in\ position\ m) = 0.2\ , m \neq n
$$

This table shows the probability of a card (row) being in a given position (column).

```
|   | 1   | 2   | 3   |
| 1 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.2 | 0.6 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.6 |
```

Now, let's say we know card $c_2$ is in position 1. We'll get the following table:

```
|   | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | ? | ? |
| 2 | 1 | ? | ? |
| 3 | 0 | ? | ? |
```

This is the problem point. How to fill in the rest?

For any solution the following should be true using the values from the tables with all possible i, j.
$$
P(c_i\ in\ position\ j) = P(c_i\ in\ position\ j\ |\ c_1\ in\ position\ 1)P(c_1\ in\ position\ 1) + P(c_i\ in\ position\ j\ |\ c_2\ in\ position\ 1)P(c_2\ in\ position\ 1) + P(c_i\ in\ position\ j\ |\ c_3\ in\ position\ 1)P(c_3\ in\ position\ 1)
$$
I was able to figure out the correct answer is of the following form.

```
|   | 1 | 2     | 3     |       |   | 1 | 2   | 3   |       |   | 1 | 2   | 3   |
| 1 | 1 | 0     | 0     |       | 1 | 0 | t   | 1-t |       | 1 | 0 | 1-t | t   |
| 2 | 0 | 1-t/3 | t/3   |       | 2 | 1 | 0   | 0   |       | 2 | 0 | t   | 1-t |
| 3 | 0 | t/3   | 1-t/3 |       | 3 | 0 | 1-t | t   |       | 3 | 1 | 0   | 0   |
```

$0 \leq t \leq 1$

This still leaves infinitely many possible answers. What's the correct value of t and how would I calculate it?

I'm trying to find a way of solving this kind of problem for any given deck, not just this example.

Comment: You can also calculate conditional probabilities of the sort: $P(c\text{ in position }16\mid d\text{ in position }1)$

Answer (score 2):

The chance for any card other than $c$ to be first is now $\frac 1{51}$.  If you are not asking about positions $16,17,18$ the chance for any given card to be in the next position is $1$ divided by the number of unknown cards less one, to account for the fact that we know it is not $c$.  For example, if you deal five cards, the chance for any given card to be next is $\frac 1{46}$.  For positions $16,17,18$ you have the chance that $c$ is there, so scale down all the other cards appropriately.  If you have dealt $5$ cards, there are $46$ non-$c$ cards reamaining.  The chance that any given one is in position $17$ is $(1-0.2)\frac 1{46}$

Comment: This works for the given example but doesn't help in a general case. Another example: cards c(1) to c(52) where c(n) has .2 chance to be in position n and .8/51 chance to be anywhere else. The calculation gets more complicated.

Comment: As your input becomes more complicated, the calculations will become more complicated, too.